# What is the correct MIME type for mail and phone numbers?

Tags: android, uri, nfc, mime-types, ndef

I am currently working on NFC Android with NdefRecords on NFC tags. To store a business card (VCard), using this MIME type was enough:

```
text/vcard
```

But what is the MIME type for e-mail addresses or phone numbers?

Alternatively, can you suggest a good solution to write phone numbers and e-mail addresses onto NFC tags?

Comment: what about `text/plain`?

Comment: text/plain working only for normal text. If I use text/plain NFC reader read it as a normal text it should not

Comment: I use `*/*` for eMails, since I use attachments

Comment: I think i made a mistake while forming the record. Can you please show the code for forming email record format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way for storing telephone numbers (to make a call) and e-mail links (without passing a whole business card) would be to use URI records.

For a telephone call (for the number +431234567), the URI would be

```
tel:+431234567
```

On Android you can create an NDEF record containing that URI using

```
NdefRecord callUri = NdefRecord.createUri("tel:+431234567");
```

Or for sending an SMS:

```
NdefRecord callUri = NdefRecord.createUri("sms:+431234567?body=MyMessage");
```

For an e-mail (to myname@example.com), the URI would be

```
mailto:myname@example.com
```

On Android you can create an NDEF record containing that URI using

```
NdefRecord mailtoUri = NdefRecord.createUri("mailto:myname@example.com");
```

Btw. besides a simple recipient address, the `mailto:` URI scheme (as well as the `sms:`URI scheme) supports additional parameters like `subject` to specify a message subject and `body` to specify a message text (see the relevant RFCs for a full description of those capabilities, but note that Android does not support all of them). For example

```
NdefRecord mailtoUri = NdefRecord.createUri("mailto:myname@example.com?subject=mysubject&body=mytext");
```

will create an NDEF record for a ready-made e-mail message to myname@example.com with the subject "mysubject" and the message body "mytext".

Comment: Yes this working fine. But for mail its pre-fill only mailto section also I need to pre-fill subject and body section.any suggestion? Kindly waiting for your reply.

Comment: Have you tried using `mailto:myname@example.com?subject=something&body=mytext`?

Comment: Can you please update your answer with your comment?

Answer (score 3):

This is my code I use to send emails with text and multiple attachments:

```
private final void sendEmailWithMultipleAttachments
(
    final String[] to, final String[] cc, final String[] bcc,
    final String subject, final String body, final List<String> filePaths
) throws ActivityNotFoundException
{
    final Intent tnt =
        new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    ////tnt.setType("plain/text");
    //tnt.setType("text/plain");
    //tnt.setType("message/rfc822");
    //tnt.setType("text/xml");
    tnt.setType("*/*");
    tnt.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
    //tnt.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, cc);
    //tnt.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_BCC, bcc);
    tnt.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    //tnt.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);

    if (filePaths != null)
    {
        // It has to be an ArrayList
        final ArrayList<Uri> URIs = new ArrayList<Uri>();
        // Convert from paths to Android friendly Parcelable URIs
        for (final String file : filePaths)
        {
            final File fileIn = new File(file);
            if (fileIn.exists())
            {
                final Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
                URIs.add(u);
            }
        }
        tnt.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, URIs);
    }

    // TEST ONLY:
    /*
    System.out.println("to     : " + to[0]);
    System.out.println("subject: " + subject);
    System.out.println("file/s : " + filePaths.size());
    */

    // It has to be "this"!!
    //this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(tnt, ""));
    //this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(tnt, "Choose an eMail Client"));
    /*
    // Without the "Use this actios as default" checkbox
    startActivity
    (
        Intent.createChooser
        (
            tnt, getString(R.string.choose)
        )
    );
    */
    // With the "Use this actios as default" checkbox
    startActivity(tnt);
}
```

Comment: I don't have any clue about NFC/NDEF

Answer (score 0):

With NFC you can use the mime type vcard. We have used e.g. "text/x-vCard" and it works fine, even including a photo.